# header elements not aligning on small screens

Tags: html, css, responsive

I was practicing some webdesign skills and there is a problem here which is,the header on the full screen will not let it's elements get out but on mall screens it's the opposite:
here is the picture of it on the big screen:
[image]

And here is a picture from a small screen:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Responsive html practice site</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="header">
                 <div class="lgcontainer">
                        <h1 class="ib">Sonora</h1><img class="ib" src="img/images/logo.jpg" />
                 </div>
            <div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

here is the css:

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.lgcontainer
{
    margin:0 0 0 3.5%;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    height:inherit;
}

.lgcontainer h1
{
    margin:0 0 10% 0;
}

.lgcontainer img
{
    margin:5% 0 0 5%;
}

.header
{
 width:100%;
 background:linear-gradient(#393a3b, #000000);
 color:white;
 height:65px;

    }

.ib
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I need to have it same as it is on full screen

Comment: make h1 display inline-block and give a try

Comment: make css Media query for small screen. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: the ib class is applied to both img and h1

Comment: may be margin on the is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `.lgcontainer` `width` to `100%` and the `text-align` to `left`. Here is the css code:

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.lgcontainer
{
    margin:0 0 0 3.5%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    height:inherit;
}

.lgcontainer h1
{
    margin:0 0 10% 0;
}

.lgcontainer img
{
    margin:1% 0 0 5%;
}

.header
{
 width:100%;
 background:linear-gradient(#393a3b, #000000);
 color:white;
 height:65px;

    }

.ib
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqGKLx